# React: How to close "loader" after getting file from api completed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem of stopping "loader" after dowloading file will stops fetching. In my case after `handleDownload()`, loader is still displaying on the screen, because it's state becomes true after clicking the button.
**inside render()**

```html
 <div className={`upload-file ${isLoading ? "is-loading-upload" : ""}`}>
      <div className="loader">
           <div className="icon" />
      </div>
  ...
  <button
    className="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-success"
    onClick={() => this.handleDownload(file)}>
     Dowload
  </button>
 </div>
```

**handleDownolad()**

```js
  handleDownload = file => {
    Axios.get("/api/files/download", { responseType: "blob", params: { file } })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", file);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        console.log(file);
      });
  };
```

At the beginning `isLoading` states as `true` and after I get some data it becomes falsy till triggering `handleDownload()`.

Comment: download is handed off to the browser when you do `link.click`. There is not much way for you to know when the download is complete..

Comment: Probably, while asking question I didn't write it correctly. I just needed to close loading after it will complete `Axios.get`, not after it will complete dowloading. Btw, thanks for response, didn't mention before that I can not work with browser events while dowload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

```
handleDownload = file => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }); // Set true flag here
    Axios.get("/api/files/download", { responseType: "blob", params: { file } })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", file);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // Set false flag here
        console.log(file);
      });
  };
```